# Element placed with CSS :after selector starts out hidden in CSS3 animation

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a CSS3 animation of a Christmas label on a string that drops down from the top of the browser window, pauses, and then retracts. The label's string is currently a separate image that is added to the label image via the `:after` CSS selector.

Here is an example on Codepen http://codepen.io/KurtWM/full/KAxpk that is set up to run over and over for troubleshooting purposes.

Nine times out of ten, the very first time the animation runs, **the string image is hidden**. It is not missing, it just does not show up. But then if you do something to the window, like re-size it, or right click and select "Inspect Element" (if you are running Developer Tools) the string will suddenly appear:

**Here is the initial run of the page with the string hidden:**
[image: On first run there is no string image showing.]

**And here the string appears when the window is re-sized:**
[image: Try re-sizing the browser window and the string image appears.]

I cannot figure out why the string will not show up initially. Sometimes it will suddenly show up after a delay, but usually you have to "tweak" the browser in some way to get it to show up.

I will probably end up having to manually add a string image, but I am really puzzled as to why this is happening. Any solutions will be appreciated.

**Simplified Code (some animation steps removed and using only -webkit- properties):**

```
/* ************************************* */
/* Animations
/* ************************************* */
@-webkit-keyframes fade-out {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(Opacity=0);
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(Opacity=0);
  }
  55% {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(Opacity=100);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(Opacity=100);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes swing {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -460px);
  }
  16% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  92% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -460px);
  }
}

/* ************************************* */
/* Element styles */
/* ************************************* */
#stage {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.swing:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -110px;
  left: 46%;
  z-index: 20;
  content: url(http://www.johnsonferry.org/portals/0/assets/newsevents/images/CP-string.png);
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
  filter: url(#drop-shadow);
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Dropshadow(OffX=2, OffY=2, Color='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)')";
  filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Dropshadow(OffX=2, OffY=2, Color='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)')";
}

.swing:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 10;
  content: url(http://www.johnsonferry.org/portals/0/assets/newsevents/images/CP-gift-label-back.png);
  -webkit-animation: fade-out 8.5s ease 5s infinite normal;
}

.swing {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 250px;
  margin-left: -125px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -460px);
  /* animate the swing with pendulum-style easing */
  -webkit-animation: swing 8.5s ease-in-out 5s infinite normal;
  animation: swing 8.5s ease-in-out 5s infinite normal;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 46% -110px 0;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.shadowed {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(6px 9px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
  filter: url(#drop-shadow);
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Dropshadow(OffX=6, OffY=9, Color='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)')";
  filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Dropshadow(OffX=6, OffY=9, Color='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)')";
}
```

Comment: It's working for me in FF 26.0a2 on Windows XP.

Comment: Thanks, Ian. I just checked in FF and it is working for me as well, although I could swear it wasn't earlier. It also seems to be working in IE _GASP!_ So maybe it is isolated to Chrome? I will most likely just stop using the :after selector, but the mystery is still irking me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that I have isolated the problem to a bug related to the animation, the pseudo element and the filter.

I have it working with this CSS (changing a property by an animation). I am showing only the  changes !

```
.swing:after {

  -webkit-animation: shadow 0.5s infinite;
/*
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
*/
}

@-webkit-keyframes shadow {
  0% { -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));}
  100% {  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 1, 0.5));}
}
```

Notice that the animation is pretty much a fake (I mean, it doesn't animate much), but looks like it's working. I guess that it makes Chrome recalculate the filter, that somehow was at the root of the problem.

Comment: Thank you, @vals! I am not yet sure why this works, but it certainly seems that it does. Here are examples of [the original version](http://codepen.io/KurtWM/pen/KAxpk) and the [version with your changes applied](http://codepen.io/KurtWM/full/Bgpoy) (I made the shadow blue to make it easier to differentiate). Opening them in Chrome shows how your solution worked.

Comment: Glad that it helped. I really don't know why it works, but the idea was that since a browser refresh solved it, to produce the refresh automatically.